# synchronize method with progress dialog

Tags: android

I have loadData() which used to load my Neuroph network.

I want to run it with a progress dialog but if part of loadData() execute i increase my progress dialog.

I need tutorial for it.

I know Thread with Handler, AsyncTask. but cannot do that with these two methods.

Answer (score 1):

So i recommend to you use meant `AsyncTask` that is specified for updating `UI` with some progress. This tool contains three the most important methods:

**doInBackground** - It's doing your work in background Thread.

**onProgressUpdate** - For updating your `UI`(in your case here you can incrementing your progress for ProgressDialog)

**onPostExecute** - It's called after your work finished.

Then, `AsyncTask` is strong tool, is very efficient and also using generics so is type-safe. But you need to read more about it so first have look at [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and then i recommend to you have look at [Android Threads, Handlers and AsyncTask](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html) on Vogella, it's great source.

Then you want to use `ProgressDialog`.
So simply create it and `show()` it before you execute `AsyncTask`. Then in **onPostExecute** method you just call **dismiss** method for dismissing **ProgressDialog**.

```
ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
pd.setProgress(0);
pd.setTitle("Some title");
pd.setMessage("Some message...");
pd.show();
yourTask.execute(); // here you are executing your AsyncTask
```

Then in your OnPostExecute method just call dismiss:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
   pd.dismiss(); // dismissing your ProgressDialog
}
```